# Using DeviceEnumeration - connecting IP based camera to windows

Tags: c#

I am needing some help. Not very strong into coding but I need to understand why something isn't running for me. 
I need to be able to connect an IP based camera to Windows. This is a new feature for windows when 1903 was released. If you look at the link below you will see what I'm referring to. 
https://www.howtogeek.com/443847/windows-10-is-getting-built-in-support-for-network-cameras/

The issue is - the cameras I'm using require a password. This is not as simple as going in and adding the device manually. If you see the document below, the "Custom device" pairing is what I'm needing done.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pair-devices

As you can see this has to be coded to accomplish what I need. So this source code was referred to in the link below as something that should be able to do it.

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/cs

Doing this in C#. Edit: I made sure to put all the shared files in the CS folder.

I'm using Visual studio and i pulled up the entire project but when I run it i'm getting an error that "The parent file, 'Scenario1_DevicePicker.xaml', for the file 'Scenario1_DevicePicker.xaml.cs' cannot be found in the project file.

I get that error for each .cs and .xaml.cs file there is. (Scenarios 1-9)

Can anyone help me out? Perhaps nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: You have to also copy the files from https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/shared into the same directory. These are the XAML files that contain the dialog layouts. There are in a shared directory because they are the same for all programming languages.

Comment: The XAML files are in `..\shared` and referenced from there. Did you properly clone the repository, or extract the entire zip?

Comment: @NineBerry I copied those in the cs folder and still same error. Do they go in a different folder?

Comment: @CodeCaster I extracted the entire zip, not sure how to clone it...but i'll start looking into that now

Comment: anyone? still needing help on this